# iOS Keyboard - Set Propertiess such as keyboardAppearance Programmatically at Application Level

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, keyboard, uikit

Is there a way to access the iOS keyboard (which seems like a global operating-system-level object) anywhere from the code?

At the moment it seems like I can set keyboardAppearance through traits, but I'd like to be able to set these programmatically from arbitrary locations in the App (e.g. in AppDelegate).

The reason we'd like to do this, in this particular case, is to prevent the keyboard colour from changing based on background.

Answer (score 3):

you can only change it to a predefined style, like UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert or UIKeyboardAppearanceDark for example.

Edit : here is the full list

```
   UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault,
   UIKeyboardAppearanceDark,
   UIKeyboardAppearanceLight,
   UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert,
```

to change it for your whole app :

```
[[UITextField appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
```

to change it for only one textfield :

```
[myTextField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
```

Comment: Nice. Makes an easy preference setting too.